# how do i create this coin flip game in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, comparison-operators

Ok so am new to Javascript and am trying to learn. 
I know this is lengthy, but I would appreciate any help. 
This is the problem I am working on:

Coin Flip Game

1. Begin you application by creating a variable called coinFlip and set it equal to a random number using the Math method.
2. Prompt the user to select "Heads or Tails" and set the result to a new variable called "choice".
3. Use a conditional to check the result of the coin flip. If it's less than a certain number, it will be heads. If it is greater than a certain number, it will be tails.
4. If the result is heads and the user selects heads, display the following message within an alert "The flip was heads and you chose heads...you win!".
5. If the result is heads and the user selects tails, display the following message within an alert: "The flip was heads but you chose tails...you lose!"
6. If the result is tails and the user selects heads, display the following message within an alert box: "The flip was tails but you chose heads...you lose!"
7. If the result is tails and the user selects tails, display the following message within an alert: "The flip was tails and you chose tails...you win!"

This is my code so far:
(I feel like I am going down the wrong path)

```
var coinFlip = Math.random();

var coinFlip = prompt("Heads or Tails?");

var coinFlip = var choice;

var choice = Math.random();
```

Comment: Why are you using the same `coinFlip` variable for 3 different things? And what is `var coinFlip = var choice;` supposed to mean? `var` is used for declaring new variables, it can't be used after `=`. What is `choice` supposed to be?

Comment: You probably meant `var choice = prompt("Heads or Tails?");`

Comment: The code you've shown makes no attempt to implement the logic of the program.  It doesn't even set the variables properly. You need to review your JavaScript tutorial and learn how to use variables properly.

Comment: The instructions tell you the exact logic you have to implement. Just write the corresponding `if()` statements.

Comment: Yes var choice = prompt("Heads or Tails?"); seems to work better.

Comment: Yes I understand, I only started studying Javascript a few days ago. Lots to learn.

Comment: SO is not a programming school. You need to learn the basics first.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it directly answers a student's homework problem before they invested any significant effort in solving it themselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to read each bit carefully. Here's how I'd do it:

1 . Begin you application by creating a variable called coinFlip and set it equal to a random number using the Math method.

For this, I would get a random number between `1` and `2` like so:

```
var coinFlip = Math.round(Math.random()) + 1;
```

2. Prompt the user to select "Heads or Tails" and set the result to a new variable called "choice".

Here's how I'd solve that:

```
var choice = prompt("Heads or Tails");
```

3. Use a conditional to check the result of the coin flip. If it's less than a certain number, it will be heads. If it is greater than a certain number, it will be tails.

Here I'd just use an `if-else` statement like so:

```
if (coinFlip == 1) {
    var flipResult = "heads";
} else {
    var flipResult = "tails";
}
```

4-7. All the win/loss `if-else` statements:

```
if (flipResult == choice) {
    if (flipResult == "heads") {
        alert("The flip was heads and you chose heads...you win!");
    } else {
        alert("The flip was tails and you chose tails...you win!");
    }
} else {
    if (flipResult == "heads") {
        alert("The flip was heads and you chose tails...you lose!");
    } else {
        alert("The flip was tails and you chose heads...you lose!");
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Note: you must enter either "heads" or "tails" in the prompt (case-sensitive) for the code to work.

Comment: Thank you so much ! You are awesome! Works Perfect.